# Importing the same Python object from the same file but from two different locations results in two different object types

Tags: python, object

I have a project organized in directories as follows:

```
|main_dir/
|        /__init__.py
|        /core/
|             /__init__.py
|             /foo.py
|             /test1.py            
|        /scr/
|            /test2.py
```

In foo.py, I define a class as follows

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

This is what I have in core/test1.py

```
from foo import foo
f1=foo()
print(type(f1))
```

This is what I have in scr/test2.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from core.foo import foo

f2 = foo()
print(type(f2))
```

`main_dir/__init__.py` contains this:

```
__all__ = ["core"]

import sys, os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

for subpackage in __all__:
     sys.path.append(os.path.join(dir,subpackage))
```

`and core/__init__.py` contains:

```
__all__ = ["foo"]
import sys, os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

for subpackage in __all__:
   sys.path.append(os.path.join(dir,subpackage))
```

When I run test1.py, the result is `class 'foo.foo'>` while when I run test2.py, I get `<class 'core.foo.foo'>`. I understand that this is how Python behaves, but I am not sure how to get around it. I would like to get `True` when checking `type(f1) == type(f2)` as I need to access the object `foo` for different locations.

Answer (score 1):

Add the first two lines from test2.py:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```

to the top of test1.py. Then change your imports of foo in test1.py and test2.py to use the fully-qualified name:

```py
from main_dir.core.foo import foo
```

Afterward:

```
# core/test.py
<class 'main_dir.core.foo.foo'>
# scr/test2.py
<class 'main_dir.core.foo.foo'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in file core/test1.py You can try to import foo like this

```
from .foo import foo
```

with the dot before the file name to ensure that is the file in the same directory gave it a try

or

You can import foo using as like it down

```
from .foo import foo as foo_one
from core.foo import foo as foo_core
```

I hope I understand what do you need and I hope it will help

Comment: "from .foo import" didn't work. I get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.foo'; '__main__' is not a package. Tried changing "__all__ = ["foo"]" in __init__.py to "__all__ = [".foo"]" but it didn't help.